# Slack app on Mac - Is # everyone channel generated automatically?

Tags: slack

The cannel list of Slack app on my Mac shows a channel called **#everyone**.
I can't remember joining or creating such a channel?
Is **#everyone** channel generated automatically by Slack?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Slack support regarding my question here and this is the response:

> I've checked this internally with the team here and can confirm that
>   we have changed the name of the #general channel to #everyone for a
>   small number of new teams. The aim of this change is to help with some
>   user confusion around the difference between #general and #random and
>   why you can't leave #general.
>
> If you're not happy with the change in name, you're free to rename
>   this back to #general by hitting the gear ion > Additional options >
>   Rename this channel.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only channel that is auto generated by Slack as far as I know is the #general channel.

Not sure this question is entirely on topic as per SO guidelines:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Maybe look at stackexchange, there appears to a wealth of Slack related questions and answers there.